# WebDriver Actions.Perform() or Actions.Build().Perform()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I use Selenium2 WebDriver with C#

Actions.Build - returns a composite `IAction` which can be used to perform the actions. (IActions has a Perform method to execute the actions)
Actions.Perform - Performs the currently built action.

In most of the examles use Actions like this:

```
new Actions(IWebDriverObj).actions...Build().Perform()
```

but this works as well

```
new Actions(IWebDriverObj).actions...Perform()  //no Build before Perform
```

Is it necessary to use the Build() before the Perform() or Build() is for some compatibility purpose only?

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Always keep in mind that Selenium is open source.

The source of `WebDriver/Interactions/Actions.cs` is [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/Actions.cs), clearly you can see `Perform()` includes `Build()`, so the answer is no, you don't need to build before perform, unless you want to pass the built `IAction` around without performing.

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Builds the sequence of actions.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A composite <see cref="IAction"/> which can be used to perform the actions.</returns>
public IAction Build()
{
    CompositeAction toReturn = this.action;
    this.action = new CompositeAction();
    return toReturn;
}

/// <summary>
/// Performs the currently built action.
/// </summary>
public void Perform()
{
    this.Build().Perform();
}
```

Also, for anyone else reading this post:

Java binding: `build()` is included in `perform()`. Source:  [interactions/Actions.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java)

Ruby/Python: only have `perform`, no such thing called `build`. Source: [action_chains.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py), [action_builder.rb](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `.perform()` includes a `.build()`.

So you can only write : `new Actions(IWebDriverObj).actions....perform()`