# Wbdriver Actions build.perform()

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can anybody tell me the difference between `build.perform()` and `perform()` in Selenium actions?

Example:

```
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
```

and

```
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your scenario it wont make a difference using both. The difference occurs at place when you have multiple actions to be performed like:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
builder.clickAndHold(element1)
.clickAndHold(element2)
.click()
.build()
.perform();
```

in the above code we are performing more than one operations so we have to use build() to compile all the actions into a single step. Thus build() method is used compile all the listed actions into a single step.
We use build() when we are performing sequence of operations and no need to use if we are performing single action.

Comment: Hey @Vivek Singh I have a question when we can build and perform with the Actions class itself then what is the need of Action interface.For example:   Actions a =new Actions(driver);  Action b = a.doubleClick(element).build(); b.perform(); we can execute the same using a.doubleClick(element).build().perform();

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but you don't have to use `build()` unless you want to pass an `IActions` object, as `build()` is done by `perform()` (see [WebDriver Actions.Perform() or Actions.Build().Perform()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435798/webdriver-actions-perform-or-actions-build-perform))